# Accessing struct in 2d array outside of declaring function

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I'm trying to access a returned 2d array of structs i create. I can access them with in the func they were created in but seem to lose the reference as i pass it out.
I have tired a thousand ways to do it, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.
Always with the seg faults.

my current run at it looks like:

a simple struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int weight;
} myStruct_t;
```

a function that creates a 2-d array for myStruct_t's.
My current attempt to get it out is to make a new variable to act as a pointer to "map", as seen in the last 2 lines.

```
myStruct_t*** makeGrid(int sizeX, int sizeY)
{  
    int i;

    myStruct_t **map = malloc(sizeX * sizeof(*map));  

    if(map == NULL){
        printf("Unable to set memory, Exiting\n");
        exit(1);
    }else{  
        for ( i = 0; i < sizeX; i++)
        {
            map[i] = malloc(sizeY*sizeof(myStruct_t));

            if(map[i] == NULL)
            {
                printf("Unable to set memory, Exiting\n");
                exit(1);
            }else{
                printf("success!\n");
            }
        }
    }

    myStruct_t ***mapPtr = &map;
    return mapPtr;  
}
```

then in another file:

```
void initSys(){
    myStruct_t** map = *myStruct_t(100,100);    
    map[0][0].weight = 7;

   //or i also just tried
   //myStruct_t*** map = myStruct_t(100,100);
   //(*map)[0][0].weight = 7;

}
```

output is a SegFault.
its amazing how quickly i have totally forgoten C memory management and i cant seem to get it back!

any suggestions would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is on the line

```
myStruct_t ***mapPtr = &map;
```

It should be:

```
 return map;
```

And you'll need to change your return type to a double pointer.

When you return "&map" you are returning the address of the variable `map`. As the variable `map` is stored on the stack, you are returning an address to invalid memory.

Comment: i returned map and changed myStruct_t** map = *myStruct_t(100,100) to myStruct_t** map = myStruct_t(100,100);. Still SefFaults